# How to set indentation for code compilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, indentation

I am looking at moving to Typescript and I am starting off by simply naming my *.js files as *.ts and compiling them.

My JS is written against the Google JS Code Style, using 2 spaces for an indent, but TS is compiling the code with 4 spaces per indent.

I have not been able to find any info about how to set the indent size when TS compiles the code, is it even possible?

If not, what are my options? Stop using Google Code Style?

Comment: Why would you care about the output style? Are you running it against a linter or a format checker?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have any restrictions on the indentation of your code. Are you talking about ESLint? Or do you want to change the output indent?

Comment: Why do you want the compiled code to match a style guide? You should be minimizing (uglyfying if that's your thing) that code anyway since it is output ready for serving and not editing.

Comment: Here are the compiler options: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html. As you can see, there are no options for the indentation. What you could do is run Prettier on the generated `*.js` files, although I'm not really sure why you would care about the indentation in them. As other said, the `*.js` files should be concatenated and minified before being deployed in production. Also, you shouldn't push the `*.js` files in your Git repository, only the `*.ts` ones.

Answer (score 3):

Like others have said, if you absolutely need to format your code after compilation, use a formatter with your preferred options after the code is compiled. [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) is the standard for that kind of stuff.

With that said, unless you have a specific use case that has not been disclosed, there's usually absolutely no reason to format your compiled code as it should be considered generated/non-editable. That's probably why you haven't found an answer for that, and why the compiler has no options for that.

Also, just like others have said again, prior to proper deployment, you should be *minifying* the code, not formatting it. There are [several tools](https://github.com/privatenumber/minification-benchmarks) for that. But if the code will be *used* by others as a dependency first, that is not necessary, as their own process should have a minification step at the end.